# GTK+ 3.0 Clipboard doesn't paste anything to my clipboard

Tags: python, tkinter, gtk

I've been using this script for testing.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
board = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD)
board.set_text("hello there", -1)
board.store()
```

It does erase anything I have in my clipboard, but it doesn't add "hello there". It just leaves empty my clipboard. It seems like other people who have used this script say that it works, so I'm not really sure about what could be causing this.

[I've used this as my resource.](https://andrewsteele.me.uk/learngtk.org/tutorials/python_gtk3_tutorial/html/clipboard.html)

Edit: This also happens to me with tkinter, so I believe that it might not be exclusive to GTK. It's probably client-side.

Tkinter code I've used to test:

```
from tkinter import Tk
r = Tk()
r.withdraw()
r.clipboard_clear()
r.clipboard_append('i can has clipboardz?')
r.destroy()
```

Comment: It works on my system!  What is your DE?

Comment: Thanks for helping me confirm it. I'm not really sure why it's not working in my system though. I hope that someone can help me with it.

Comment: i3wm. Could it be fault of the DE?

Comment: I am not sure, but if it was something I have around here, I could test.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either (Python 3.4 on Windows 10).

Comment: Rawing, could you do me a favor and tell me if you can make it work with Tkinter?

Comment: ... tkinter also works fine here (Ubuntu Unity 16.04)

Comment: Tkinter does something very odd... I had to change your code a little (`r.after(100, r.destroy); r.mainloop()` instead of `r.destroy()`), and now it works, but only if I press ctrl+v while the python interpreter is still running. If I close python, then try to paste, nothing happens. But if I paste first, then close python, I can keep pasting forever.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, sort of. It seems like I've been able to import the [xerox library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xerox) without GTK complaining, and it worked. It's still not the best solution, but at least it's a workarround.